# MySQL Semi synchronous replication stuck

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I have a mysql semi-synchronous replica-set with a master and 2 slaves. The replication happens fine to only one of the nodes but the other node is always stuck with the following status.
Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event

Master does not send any data and I see the following in the master mysqld error logs.

> 2018-05-14T06:43:51.880292Z 113 [ERROR] Semi-sync master failed on
>   net_flush() before waiting for slave reply
>
> 2018-05-14T06:43:51.880985Z 113 [Note] Stop semi-sync binlog_dump to
>   slave (server_id: 111)
>
> 2018-05-14T06:44:41.754052Z 1343 [Note] While initializing dump thread
>   for slave with UUID <770ca92e-5730-11e8-9f7a-000d3a064af1>, found a
>   zombie dump thread with the same UUID. Master is killing the zombie
>   dump thread(113).
>
> 2018-05-14T06:44:41.863759Z 1343 [Note] Start binlog_dump to
>   master_thread_id(1343) slave_server(111), pos(, 4)
>
> 2018-05-14T06:46:11.934785Z 1382 [Note] While initializing dump thread
>   for slave with UUID <770ca92e-5730-11e8-9f7a-000d3a064af1>, found a
>   zombie dump thread with the same UUID. Master is killing the zombie
>   dump thread(113).
>
> 2018-05-14T06:46:11.934894Z 1382 [Note] Start binlog_dump to
>   master_thread_id(1382) slave_server(111), pos(, 4)
>
> 2018-05-14T06:47:11.985863Z 1408 [Note] While initializing dump thread
>   for slave with UUID <770ca92e-5730-11e8-9f7a-000d3a064af1>, found a
>   zombie dump thread with the same UUID. Master is killing the zombie
>   dump thread(113).

and so on....

my slave_net_timeout is 60 s on the slave and I can clearly see that after every 60 s the slave is trying to reconnect, but the master acknowledges and holds the connection but does not send any data. As a side effect, the number of slave connections to master continuously grows. I also see the following in Show Processlist for the master:

> 113 | repl_user | 172.19.0.12:58174    | NULL | Binlog Dump GTID |
>   3189 | Waiting to finalize termination                               |
>   NULL
>           | 1343 | repl_user | 172.19.0.12:35394    | NULL | Binlog Dump GTID |  418 | starting
>   | NULL    |
>
> | 1382 | repl_user | 172.19.0.12:35572    | NULL | Binlog Dump GTID | 
>   328 | starting                                                      |
>   NULL             |

Any pointers and to debug this further will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: If one replica is a clone of the other, and both have their `@@server_uuid` set to `770ca92e-5730-11e8-9f7a-000d3a064af1`, this would be expected behavior.  The `@@server_id` values should also be different, though it may not matter for GTID.  Check these values?

Comment: Hi - I have ensured that server uuid each host is different.